# How does .NET know when to continue to the next line of code?

Tags: c#, .net

I wrote this little bit of C# code to test an implementation I intend to use for an internal tool at work.  Much to my surprise, it functions exactly as I hoped but I do not understand why.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadFile("http://url censored", @"C:\Users\Dustin\Desktop\flashplayer.exe");

        bool dlComplete = System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Dustin\Desktop\flashplayer.exe");

        if (dlComplete == true)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Dustin\Desktop\flashplayer.exe");
        }
        else
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Something's jacked!");
        }

    }
```

When I press on `button1`, my machine downloads the Flash installer *and then* checks if the file exists (this is my roundabout way of avoiding event handlers which I have not learned to deal with yet), and continues on.

Why doesn't my computer check for the file's existence *while* the file is downloading? How does this wizard of a computer know to hold on a moment while the file download completes?

Comment: DownloadFile is called a **synchronous** method, it means that the program will stop excecution until the method has finished

Comment: have you tried a "large" file?

Comment: @geekzster No but I did monitor my desktop and determine that the behavior I described is what is taking place.  Should I?

Comment: I'd be interested to know why my question was downvoted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WebClient.DownloadFile` is a ***Synchronous*** method in which downloads to a local data file.

As stated on the MSDN link [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144194(v=vs.110).aspx) - "[t]his methods ***blocks*** while downloading the resource."

In other words, the process is waiting for completion (*blocking the calling function*), before returning control and execution to the thread.

This results in the *wizardry* you're experiencing with the application knowing when to check for the file's presence. I know magic can be ruined once you know the trick; however, I hope this ins't the case..

Comment: It's not so much the trick itself that ruined the magic; it's how fast you spotted the trick.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For reference, here's a way that would work the way you didn't expect, *asynchronously.*

```
var webClient = new WebClient())
webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
webClient.DownloadFileAsync("http://www.server.com/file.txt", "C:\\file.txt");
```

In fact, there's a whole set of Asynchronous C# functions. It's worth reading up on if you're interested in getting into development.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx

Comment: Aha! This is that event handling stuff that I haven't learned about yet and was trying to avoid (only because I haven't learned about it yet).  Thanks for the info!  I will study up.

Comment: May I suggest starting with this blog? It's not mine, but it taught me a lot about async / await in C#
It may be scary and super confusing at first, but I promise, once you get the hang of it, you'll love the simplicity and ease of Tasks and the Task Parallel Library (TPL) over the thread pool and raw threads. :)
http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html